# Is there no unit testing framework in the iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

Is there no unit testing framework in the iphone sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes. see this link on unit testing for iphone (3.0 and up) [Unit Testing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html)

Answer (score 3):

I do it through XCode

See [guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html)

Answer (score 0):

Better frameworks include [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit) and [WiteBox](http://code.google.com/p/witebox/) (from [Rapture In Venice](http://raptureinvenice.com/))